# boto copy function malfunction python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Im using the boto `copy_key` function to move a file from one folder in a bucket to another folder in the same bucket. When I run the code I don't receive an error. However when I go to my storage and download the new file, the information in the file is not the same as the original. The code I'm using to copy the key is below:

```
import boto 
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto.s3.connection

bucket = "my bucket name"
# connect to my amazon 
conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id , aws_secret_access_key ) 

bucketname = conn.get_bucket(bucket,validate=False)

bucketname.copy_key(New_location, bucket, Source_location)
```

The information in the new file look like this.

> {"filter":false,"title":"download.py","tooltip":"/temp/download.py","undoManager":{"mark":44,"position":44,"stack":[[{"start":{"row":0,"column":0},"end":{"row":22,"column":17},"action":"insert","lines":["import
>   boto, os","","LOCAL_PATH = 'tmp/'","","AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID =
>   'YOUUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'","AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =
>   'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'","bucket_name = 'your_bucket_name'","","#
>   connect to the bucket","conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
>   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)","bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)","","#
>   go through the list of files","bucket_list = bucket.list()","for l in
>   bucket_list:","  keyString = str(l.key)","  d = LOCAL_PATH +
>   keyString","  try:","    l.get_contents_to_filename(d)","  except
>   OSError:","    # check if dir exists","    if not
>   os.path.exists(d):","
>   os.mkdir(d)"],"id":1}],[{"start":{"row":2,"column":15},"end":{"row":2,"column":16},"action":"insert","lines":["e"],"id":2}],[{"start":{"row":4,"column":0},"end":{"row":5,"column":52},"action":"remove","lines":["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
>   = 'YOUUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'","AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'"],"id":3},{"start":{"row":4,"column":0},"end":{"row":7,"column":0},"action":"insert","lines":["aws_access_key_id
>   = \"\"","aws_secret_access_key = \""","",""]}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":0},"end":{"row":7,"column":0},"action":"remove","lines":["",""],"id":4}],[{"start":{"row":5,"column":66},"end":{"row":6,"column":0},"action":"remove","lines":["",""],"id":5}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":15},"end":{"row":6,"column":31},"action":"remove","lines":["your_bucket_name"],"id":6}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":15},"end":{"row":6,"column":16},"action":"insert","lines":["p"],"id":7}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":16},"end":{"row":6,"column":17},"action":"insert","lines":["e"],"id":8}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":17},"end":{"row":6,"column":18},"action":"insert","lines":["c"],"id":9}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":18},"end":{"row":6,"column":19},"action":"insert","lines":["h"],"id":10}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":19},"end":{"row":6,"column":20},"action":"insert","lines":["e"],"id":11}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":20},"end":{"row":6,"column":21},"action":"insert","lines":["t"],"id":12}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":21},"end":{"row":6,"column":22},"action":"insert","lines":["d"],"id":13}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":22},"end":{"row":6,"column":23},"action":"insert","lines":["y"],"id":14}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":23},"end":{"row":6,"column":24},"action":"insert","lines":["n"],"id":15}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":24},"end":{"row":6,"column":25},"action":"insert","lines":["a"],"id":16}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":25},"end":{"row":6,"column":26},"action":"insert","lines":["m"],"id":17}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":26},"end":{"row":6,"column":27},"action":"insert","lines":["i"],"id":18}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":27},"end":{"row":6,"column":28},"action":"insert","lines":["c"],"id":19}],[{"start":{"row":6,"column":28},"end":{"row":6,"column":29},"action":"insert","lines":["s"],"id":20}],[{"start":{"row":9,"column":23},"end":{"row":9,"column":40},"action":"remove","lines":["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],"id":21},{"start":{"row":9,"column":23},"end":{"row":9,"column":40},"action":"insert","lines":["aws_access_key_id"]}],[{"start":{"row":9,"column":42},"end":{"row":9,"column":63},"action":"remove","lines":["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],"id":22},{"start":{"row":9,"column":42},"end":{"row":9,"column":63},"action":"insert","lines":["aws_secret_access_key"]}],[{"start":{"row":2,"column":18},"end":{"row":2,"column":19},"action":"remove","lines":["/"],"id":23}],[{"start":{"row":2,"column":17},"end":{"row":2,"column":18},"action":"remove","lines":["p"],"id":24}],[{"start":{"row":2,"column":16},"end":{"row":2,"column":17},"action":"remove","lines":["m"],"id":25}],[{"start":{"row":2,"column":15},"end":{"row":2,"column":16},"action":"remove","lines":["e"],"id":26}],[{"start":{"row":2,"column":14},"end":{"row":2,"column":15},"action":"remove","lines":["t"],"id":27}],[{"start":{"row":21,"column":0},"end":{"row":22,"column":17},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   if not os.path.exists(d):","
>   os.mkdir(d)"],"id":28},{"start":{"row":21,"column":0},"end":{"row":22,"column":24},"action":"insert","lines":["if
>   not os.path.exists(newpath):","
>   os.makedirs(newpath)"]}],[{"start":{"row":18,"column":0},"end":{"row":18,"column":4},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":29}],[{"start":{"row":18,"column":0},"end":{"row":18,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "],"id":30}],[{"start":{"row":18,"column":0},"end":{"row":18,"column":4},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":31}],[{"start":{"row":15,"column":1},"end":{"row":15,"column":2},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":32}],[{"start":{"row":15,"column":0},"end":{"row":15,"column":1},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":33}],[{"start":{"row":16,"column":1},"end":{"row":16,"column":2},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":34}],[{"start":{"row":16,"column":0},"end":{"row":16,"column":1},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":35}],[{"start":{"row":17,"column":1},"end":{"row":17,"column":2},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":36}],[{"start":{"row":17,"column":0},"end":{"row":17,"column":1},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":37}],[{"start":{"row":18,"column":0},"end":{"row":18,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "],"id":38}],[{"start":{"row":19,"column":1},"end":{"row":19,"column":2},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":39}],[{"start":{"row":19,"column":0},"end":{"row":19,"column":1},"action":"remove","lines":["
>   "],"id":40}],[{"start":{"row":21,"column":0},"end":{"row":21,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "],"id":41}],[{"start":{"row":22,"column":4},"end":{"row":22,"column":8},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "],"id":42}],[{"start":{"row":22,"column":20},"end":{"row":22,"column":27},"action":"remove","lines":["newpath"],"id":43},{"start":{"row":22,"column":20},"end":{"row":22,"column":21},"action":"insert","lines":["d"]}],[{"start":{"row":15,"column":0},"end":{"row":15,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "],"id":44},{"start":{"row":16,"column":0},"end":{"row":16,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "]},{"start":{"row":17,"column":0},"end":{"row":17,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "]},{"start":{"row":18,"column":0},"end":{"row":18,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "]},{"start":{"row":19,"column":0},"end":{"row":19,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "]},{"start":{"row":20,"column":0},"end":{"row":20,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "]},{"start":{"row":21,"column":0},"end":{"row":21,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "]},{"start":{"row":22,"column":0},"end":{"row":22,"column":4},"action":"insert","lines":["
>   "]}],[{"start":{"row":21,"column":30},"end":{"row":21,"column":37},"action":"remove","lines":["newpath"],"id":45},{"start":{"row":21,"column":30},"end":{"row":21,"column":31},"action":"insert","lines":["d"]}]]},"ace":{"folds":[],"scrolltop":0,"scrollleft":0,"selection":{"start":{"row":21,"column":31},"end":{"row":21,"column":31},"isBackwards":false},"options":{"guessTabSize":true,"useWrapMode":false,"wrapToView":true},"firstLineState":0},"timestamp":1463635121677,"hash":"51d275203b744392d183282485806b7c2aa0c3b7"}

Comment: I don't see a reason to show "new file looks like this". If you want to show the different, use a difftools. if you suspect the copy_key process modify your contents, you just need to crop part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems a bit unclear which bucket you are copying to and from. Either way I have written sample code to help explain how the copy works with the appropriate descriptions

```
access_key = '...'
secret_key = '...'
# copy s3 object to new name in the SAME bucket 
my_bucket_name= 'bucketX'

conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(my_bucket_name)
# boto.s3.bucket.copy_key(new_key_name, src_bucket_name, src_key_name,...)
bucket.copy_key('new_filename.pdf', my_bucket_name , 'full/path/of/key.pdf')
```

Hopefully this was easy to understand.

Comment: it means you should put the name of the bucket name you are copying the file from.

Comment: yes and the same issue happened. with a sample text the outcome was {"filter":false,"title":"upload.py","tooltip":"/upload.py","undoManager":{"mark":-1,"position":-1,"stack":[]},"ace":{"folds":[],"scrolltop":225,"scrollleft":0,"selection":{"start":{"row":10,"column":0},"end":{"row":10,"column":0},"isBackwards":false},"options":{"guessTabSize":true,"useWrapMode":false,"wrapToView":true},"firstLineState":{"row":16,"state":"start","mode":"ace/mode/python"}},"timestamp":1463093979000,"hash":"b766903ffadab950aa112eb55f5e916def0e2cf7"}

Comment: Can you try a simple text file with just the words "hello" in it and see if your new file has the same content?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, for peace of mind, migrate to boto3.  Boto2 are poorly documented and there is no further improvement and bugfix.

Again, I am going to repeat this X time : S3 are not a file system , it is object store. In fact , the "/" is NOT a folder, it is just part of the object key name. It may use as part of arbitrary "PREFIX" in some S3 client module,but it is NOT a folder.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
mybucket ="bucketX"
old_name = "/foo/abc123456"
new_name ="/bar/abc123456"

s3.copy_object(
  Bucket=mybucket, 
  CopySource= {'Bucket': mybucket , 'Key': old_name}
  Key=new_name
)
```